# Finding maximum of a function of 2 variables

Tags: mathematical-optimization, warning-messages, physics

I have function defined in such way:

```
ω0=145199+1;       
f=1;
b=ω0/4;
s[ω_] := NDSolve[{x''[t]+b x'[t]+ω0^2 x[t]==f Sin[ω t],x[0]==0,x'[0]==0},x[t],{t,0,2π/ω0}];
x[t_,ω_]:=s[ω][[1,1,2]];
```

I'm trying to find `t` and `ω` for which the max. of the function occurs.

```
ωmax = NMaximize[{x[t,omg], 0<=t<=2π/ω0},{t, omg}]
```

Overall I am trying to find resonant frequency for which the largest oscillation occurs.
Unfortunately I get this error:
[image: error]

I have searched the reference, the stack and could not find the answer for the problem.

Comment: Can you include the definition of `f`, `b` (make sure the example you show is [complete](http://sscce.org/))

Comment: That's right, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

ω0 = 145199 + 1;
f = 1;
b = ω0/4;
```

The differential equation can be solved exactly

```
x[t_, ω_] = DSolveValue[
   {x''[t] + b x'[t] + ω0^2 x[t] == f Sin[ω t],
    x[0] == 0, x'[0] == 0}, x[t], t] //
  FullSimplify[#, 0 <= t <= 2 π/ω0] &
```

[image]

**EDIT:** Use of arbitrary precision is necessary. This is done by specifying a [`WorkingPrecision`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WorkingPrecision.html) for [`NMaximize`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NMaximize.html)

```
ωmax = 
 NMaximize[{x[t, ω], 0 <= t <= 2 π/ω0, 
    0 < ω < 2 ω0}, {t, ω}, 
   WorkingPrecision -> 50] // N

(* {7.09473*10^-11, {t -> 0.0000274786, ω -> 84877.3}} *)

Show[
 Plot3D[x[t, ω], {t, 0, 2 π/ω0}, {ω, 0, 2 ω0},
  AxesLabel -> Automatic,
  ClippingStyle -> None],
 Graphics3D[{Red, AbsolutePointSize[5], 
   Point[{t, ω, x[t, ω]} /. ωmax[[2]]]}]]
```

[image: ed]

Comment: Awesome! This value should be calculated as a product of "numerical experiment", whatever it means. It looks like I have to watch some tutorials of using mathematica to know how does it actually works. Unfortunately I have all lectures cancelled because of ncov and we were made to do something here, without any preparation etc. so I am kind of lost. Anyway thanks and I wish you good health!

Comment: @Pekureda - Note that I had to further increase the precision to get a correct value.

Comment: Yeah. Although it is not in the problem described here, I was able to get some values out of it, but only when ω was treated as constant, so I hoped I would get the answer.